# Return complete file name if only know a prefix (substring)

Tags: javascript, jquery, filenames

Using JavaScript / jQuery, how can I get the complete file name of a file, when I only know its prefix?

For example:

The folder I'm browsing contains pic files:

- 001_PicA.jpg
- 002_PicB.jpg
- 004_PicC.jpg
- 007_PicD.jpg
- 008_PicE.jpg

Now let's say in my script I only have `__002__` as information available. How could I get the complete file name (that is: `002_PicB.jpg`)?

Comment: ans ..not possible...

Comment: You question is unclear, but maybe the File API will help you? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Comment: Unless you have the file list available somewhere, not possible with JS alone. It can't list files on server directories. Not even with file API.

Comment: So if I have the file list available in PHP (as an array), how do I pass it on to jquery?

Answer (score 0):

As other said, *it is not possible to invoke directly*.  However if the list of files are available as an **`array`** then try the below approach.

Iterate each *item* in the `array` and then check for it occurance using **`idexOf()`**.

```
var fileName = ["001_PicA.jpg", "002_PicB.jpg", "003_PicC.jpg"];
var contains = [];
$.each(fileName, function (i, j) {  
    if (j.indexOf("002") != -1) {
     contains.push(j);  //push the items to the array
    }
});

console.log(contains);  //returns 002_PicB.jpg
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pa47f/2/)